# Error: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the right syntax to use near '' at line 1

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.1

SQL Query: get
i am trying to count unique views in my project and i got this error , I've looked it up and yet couldn't find any solution so here is the code that I've changed in the Controller before the error comes up :

```
class PostsController extends AppController {
    
  public $helpers = array('Html', 'Form');
  public function index()
  {
      $posts = $this->Post->find()
          ->contain(['View'])
          ->all();
      $this->set('posts', $posts);
  }
public function initialize()
{
    parent::initialize();
    $this->loadModel('Post');
    $this->loadModel('View');
}

public function view($id)
{
    $post = $this->Post->get($id);
    $userId = $this->Auth->user('id');

    $view = $this->View->find()
        ->where(['post_id' => $id, 'user_id' => $userId])
        ->first();

    if (!$view) {
        $view = $this->View->newEntity([
            'post_id' => $id,
            'user_id' => $userId,
            'referrer' => $this->referer(),
            'ip_address' => $this->request->clientIp(),
            'user_agent' => $this->request->header('User-Agent')
        ]);
        $this->View->save($view);
        $post->views += 1;
        $this->Post->save($post);
    }

    $this->set(compact('post'));
}

}
```

And here is the code in the post model :

```
public function incrementViews($id)
{
    $post = $this->findById($id);
    if ($post) {
        $this->id = $id;
        $this->saveField('views', $post['Post']['views'] + 1);
    }
}
```

and now the view model :

```
<?php
// src/Model/View.php

namespace App\Model;

use Cake\ORM\Table;

class View extends Table
{
    public function initialize(array $config): void
    {
        $this->setTable('views');
        $this->belongsTo('Posts');
        $this->belongsTo('Users');
    }
}
```

any ideas ??

Comment: 1) You need to indicate which line of code triggers the error message, otherwise you are leaving us to guess. 2) This is a "leaky abstraction" case as you do not directly interact with mysql. You need to understand what sql statements are generated by the line that triggers the error and what you can do to influence it to execute a correct sql statement.

Comment: You are again mixing CakePHP 2.x code and 3.x/4.x code. Unless you're using a compatibiilty shim, that's a problem already. If you're using such a shim, then you should mention that.